# How can I allow for multiple image uploads using node/html

Tags: html, node.js

I've recently added the capability of uploading and displaying an image in my angularjs app , however I'm in need of help when it comes allowing the user to upload multiple images instead of having the upload overwrite the same image every time , do I need to use ng-repeat in this case or is this much more complicated than I think it is ?

Code: using multer and diskStorage

```
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'image' + '.jpg') //Appending .jpg
  }
})
```

POST and GET functions:

```
app.post("/api/file" , upload.single('userFile'), function(req,res , next){


console.log('FIRST TEST :'+ JSON.stringify(req.file));

  });
app.get('/image.jpg', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(path.resolve('./uploads/image.jpg'));
});
```

Html :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/api/file">
<input type="file" name="userFile">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br><br>
<img src="/image.jpg" style="width:128px;height:128px;"/>
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any angular code posted here.  there's no controller, no `$http` making a post, and there is no `ng-app`, `ng-controller`, etc. in the HTML.  it's not obvious where angular is even involved here at all.

Comment: The app itself is an angular app but ya you're right I shouldn't have tagged this with angular , ill edit it now sorry

Comment: I suspect you probably **did** want the angular tag, especially since you asked about using `ng-repeat`;  my point is more that you seem to be doing this without angular but it would probably be easier if angular were involved.

Comment: Would it ? tbh I'm not really sure , I'm new to using MEAN stack and only now I'm learning about file and img uploading , I guess I'll look into this with angular instead , think I should take down the post then ?

Comment: well it seems to me that you are trying to treat an image as data, and since angular's chief concern is managing data, they would match up.  ultimately, you are still using an HTML form with submitting the image, but the real question is how to store it on the server in relation to all the other data, and how to retrieve it;  right now, your server is only allowing one upload for the *entire app, for all users*.

Comment: Well I can use Date.now() instead of 'image' that will enable the user to upload multiple images but the initial problem remains , which is trying to display all these images at once instead of only displaying one.